# Login to DOTNETNUKE application using Curl (Or Guzzle)

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, dotnetnuke, guzzle

I have been trying to get a small PHP script to login in to a DOTNETNUKE application for a few days now with no avail. I have copied the headers and post variables EXACTLY as they are being sent using Tamper Data plugin for firefox.

Every time I send over the data I get the following error:

> error=Your%20session%20has%20expired.%20%20Please%20try%20again

From what I can tell it's because the DOTNETNUKE Cookie is not being passed back and I am not sure why any help would be greatly appreciated. My GUZZLE code is below:

```
include_once(LIBRARY_PATH . '/guzzle.phar');

use Guzzle\Http\Client;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookiePlugin;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookieJar\ArrayCookieJar;

$cookiePlugin = new CookiePlugin(new ArrayCookieJar());

$client = new Client('ASPX URL CODE GOES HERE');
$client->addSubscriber($cookiePlugin);
$client->setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');

$response = $client->get('ASPX URL CODE GOES HERE')->send();

$request = $client->post('ASPX URL CODE GOES HERE', array(), array(
    '__EVENTTARGET' => 'dnn$ctr383$LoginPage$SearchPage$dataPanel$ctl01$ctl13$LoginButton',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT' => '',
    'dnn$ReturnModuleFocus' => '',
    'dnn$ModuleFocalPoint' => '',
    'dnn$ModuleInvokedFromDataSearch' => '',
    'dnn$ctr383$LoginPage$SearchPage$dataPanel$ctl01$ctl11$userName$mb_userName' => 'USERNAME HERE',
    'dnn$ctr383$LoginPage$SearchPage$dataPanel$ctl01$ctl12$password$mb_password' => 'PASSWORD HERE',
    'dnn$ctr383$LoginPage$SearchPage$dataPanel$ConfirmationSaveResponse' => '',
    'dnn$ctr383$LoginPage$SearchPage$dataPanel$MinMax' => '',
    'dnn$ctr383$LoginPage$SearchPage$dataPanel$dpPostBack' => '',
    'ScrollTop' => '',
    '__dnnVariable' => '',
    'ScrollX' => '0',
    'ScrollY' => '0',
    'iCWindowID' => '2',
    'iCRequestID' => '1',
    'iCFieldsChanged' => '0',
    '__VIEWSTATE' => ''
));

$response = $request->send();

echo $response;
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code it seems like you are dealing with an asp site. I'm no good with ASP but i was scraping a lot of sites built with it and your problem is the __VIEWSTATE parameter.

ASP is using this random string for some sort of weird session handling. You can solve it easily by downloading the login form page and parsing out the __VIEWSTATE hidden input field's value

Comment: I am dealing with an ASP site. However its not the __VIEWSTATE thats the issue it gets passed as a blank as you can see in my post variables above and I have tried parsing it and it seems to always stay blank.